# Can I still access AWS Web Application when EC2 is in a private subnet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, aws-vpc-peering

I am running an application on an EC2 in a public subnet. I've now been required to move this application into a private subnet but people still want to have access to the application. Previously this was done using OpenVPN with the configuration in the security group.

However, with moving the EC2 into a private subnet, would I still be able to access the web application? I've tried to do a test on a dev environment following multiple tutorials yet I don't fully understand.

Comment: A standard setup is to host Ec2 in a private subnet and expose your application through a public load balancer or API gateway.

Comment: Could you please clarify your requirements? For example, who should be able to connect to the instance -- is it just for staff members in your company? Should the access only be available when using a specific VPN connection? How do you use the application -- is it a web app, or do you login to the instance and run it from there? Why did you add a `vpc-peering` tag to your question? Basically, please Edit your Question and provide more information so that we can assist you.